# Calling instance methods from Class methods in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function-calls, instance-methods, class-method

Is this the right way of calling an Instance method from a class method? Here the instance_var is passed with the Name object. I want to invoke func1 from the instance_var object passed to the class method.

I wrote this :

```
Class Name
    def initialize
        @name
    end
    def func1(value)
        puts value
    end
    def self.func2(instance_var,val)
        instance_var.func1(val)
    end
end
```

Comment: Why would you need this? But yeah, this would be the way to go, where instance_var is an instance of the Name class

Comment: I tried this, but value did not get printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you call `func2`?

Your code has a small error. You wrote `Class` instead `class`. With `Class` you get a syntax error.

This code works:

```
class Name
    def func1(value)
        puts value
    end
    def self.func2(instance_var,val)
        instance_var.func1(val)
    end
end

x = Name.new
Name.func2(x, 12)     #12

#or
Name.func2(Name.new, 12)  #12
```

---

Your

```
    def initialize
        @name
    end
```

will create an empty variable `@name`. It will never get a value. To assign a value you need:

```
class Name
    def initialize (var)
        @name = var
    end
end

x = Name.new(:x)
```